# how can i properly run a background process in bash ,interact with that process, then kill it

Tags: python, linux, bash, curl

Im trying to write a simple self contained test script in bash that launches my web server, then tries to run curl against it, then kills the process:

```
python web.py & 

PID1=$!

sleep 3

curl -X POST -F n=hello http://127.0.0.1:5000/run

kill $PID1
```

when I do this, the curl command runs fine, but it doesnt actually kill the pid.  also how can i better coordinate waiting for the web process to finish loading.  i put a sleep in there because it can take a few seconds to fully boot up.  what would be a better way to test the webserver?

Comment: `kill $PID1` just kills the main python process. If the script spawns child processes to process requests, it won't kill them.

Comment: that was the issue, thanks! is there a better way to not use sleep in code like this?